# Uninstall custom boost libraries build

Tags: boost, uninstallation

I have a Fedora 15 64 bit system.
Somebody, some time ago, installed a custom build of boost, by using bjam. I think they needed static libs, and the Fedora distro only has the shared.
Someone else, before or after (likely me) used yum to install a set of boost-*.fc15.x86_64 libraries.
Now, things are confused, as we are finding strange linker errors, and we want to start from scratch.
I can uninstall the boost library packages with yum, but what is the best way to remove the libraries installed by bjam? I can find no docs on “removing” or “uninstalling” in our boost build distribution.
Right now I can simply delete all files 
    libboost_* under /usr/lib64:

```
/usr/lib64/libboost_*.a
/usr/lib64/libboost_*-mt.a
/usr/lib64/libboost_*-mt.so
/usr/lib64/libboost_*-mt.so.1.46.0
/usr/lib64/libboost_*.so
/usr/lib64/libboost_*.so.1.46.0
```

But is this sufficient, and a good idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Ok, using yum to uninstall boost is NOT going to work, it looks like half of Fedora depends on boost.

Comment: ... AND I must figure out where boost installed the headers. DANG.